# How to hgignore all subfolders but not the file in a folder?

Tags: regex, mercurial, nuget, hgignore

I am looking to use [nuget without committing the packages](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/03/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.html). I want to ignore in mercurial all packages subfolder that are located in the `/packages/` folder, but I do not want to exclude the `repositories.config` file located in the `/packages/` folder.

How should I write the exclusion regex to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Can't you just do this:

```
hg add packages/repositories.config
```

And then have this in your .hgignore file

```
syntax: glob

packages
```

?

Comment: The obvious is always hidden from sight. Thank you

Comment: Does that not ignore any subsequent changes to repositories.config?

Comment: @MattHamilton it doesn't ignore subsequent changes.  `.hgignore` is **only** about not showing unadded files.  Once a file has been added the `.hgignore` has no effect at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
syntax: regexp
packages/(?!repositories.config).*
```

[[source](http://rikkus-development.blogspot.com/2012/12/ignore-nuget-packages-folder-apart-from.html)]

Answer (score 0):

For ignore all jpg files with subdirectories in folder images:

```
^images/.*\.jpg$
```